# Comparing local and uploaded app screenshots with App Store Connect API

Tags: swift, cocoa, app-store-connect-api

Is there a way to compare a local app screenshot on my Mac with the one currently on App Store Connect without downloading the screenshot itself? The API returns `fileSize` and `sourceFileChecksum` properties (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/read_app_screenshot_information), but the file size of my local image is different (`url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey]).fileSize`) and the checksum is also different from the one I provided when completing the app screenshot upload.